# круговой перебор массива

Tags: php, алгоритм

```
$way = array(a,b,c,d...); //массив с элементами
$result = array(a => array(b,c,d), b => array(a,c,d),...); // что нужно получить
```

как можно подобное реализовать на php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?
$way = array(a,b,c,d);
$result = array(); 
foreach($way as $i => $data1){
    $result[$i] = array();
    foreach($way as $j => $data2)
        if($i != $j)
            $result[$i][] = $j;
}
?>
```

Comment: поправил вопрос

Comment: @user193361 поправил ответ